# Multiple-table DELETE LIMIT

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-delete

I'm trying to run following query but it throws an error.

```
DELETE b 
FROM parim_lang a 
JOIN parim_lang b 
    ON b.lang_hash = a.lang_hash 
    AND b.lang_language = SUBSTRING(a.lang_google_translation, LOCATE('-', a.lang_google_translation) + 1)
WHERE a.lang_google_translation REGEXP '^[a-z]+-[a-z]+'
LIMIT 20
```

Without limit this query works..

Error looks like this:

> SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIMIT 20' at line 7

Found this:

> For the multiple-table syntax, DELETE deletes from each tbl_name the rows that satisfy the conditions. In this case, ORDER BY and LIMIT cannot be used.

I there any workarounds for this?

Comment: `For the multiple-table syntax, DELETE deletes from each tbl_name the rows that satisfy the conditions. In this case, ORDER BY and LIMIT cannot be used.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try :

```
DELETE
FROM parim_lang a
WHERE a.lang_hash IN (
SELECT a.lang_hash 
FROM parim_lang a
JOIN parim_lang b 
    ON b.lang_hash = a.lang_hash 
    AND b.lang_language = SUBSTRING(a.lang_google_translation, LOCATE('-', a.lang_google_translation) + 1)
WHERE a.lang_google_translation REGEXP '^[a-z]+-[a-z]+' ) LIMIT 20
```

Comment: `SQL Error (1235): This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'`, i'm using version 5.5

Comment: edited, now it should work ( working on my computer on a small query example )