# Delete with join on the same table and limit clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySql table like this,

```
Session_Id Subscriber_Id Status
-------------------------------
abc     1234    Started
bcd     1235    Started
bcd     1235    Finished
```

And I need to delete rows with status 'Started' only if followed by a 'Finished'. This is a huge table, so I would be deleting 1000 records at a time.

I read up a few similar threads,
[Multiple-table DELETE LIMIT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12637193/multiple-table-delete-limit), 
[DELETE FROM `table` AS `alias` ... WHERE `alias`.`column` ... why syntax error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10484532/delete-from-table-as-alias-where-alias-column-why-syntax-error)

and tried the below queries,

```
mysql> delete a.* from FSESSION as a, FSESSION as b where a.status='Started' and b.status='Finished' and a.session_id=b.session_id limit 1000;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'limit 1000' at line 1  ----> If I remove 'limit' this works

mysql> DELETE FROM v USING `FSESSION` AS v WHERE status = 'Started' and exists(select 0 from FSESSION t where t.status='Finished' and v.session_id=t.session_id) limit 1000;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'limit 1000' at line 1 ---->
```

Does'nt work even when limit is removed.

I use MySql version 5.1.56-ndb-7.1.15. Please suggest a way to do this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATED** based on your comments

```
DELETE f
  FROM fsession f JOIN
(
  SELECT session_id, subscriber_id
    FROM fsession
   WHERE status IN('Started', 'Finished')
   GROUP BY Session_Id, Subscriber_Id
  HAVING MAX(status = 'Started')  > 0
     AND MAX(status = 'Finished') > 0
  LIMIT 1000 -- limit here means how many pairs of rows, so it's effectively 2x rows
) q ON f.session_id = q.session_id
   AND f.subscriber_id = q.subscriber_id
```

To know how many rows were deleted use `ROW_COUNT()`

```
SELECT ROW_COUNT();
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/00931/1)** demo

Comment: I need to delete 'started' and 'finished' records, but my table is bound to contain many 'finished' records without corresponding 'started' records, so my plan is to delete the 'started' records(and if possible, their corresponding 'finished' records) first and then delete the finished records. The final finished records deletion query would be a straightforward query without complex JOINS or where clauses and I can take a higher limit value, say 10000

Comment: So, ideally I need to know when my first query returns a row limit less than 1000, which would indicate there are no more 'started' records(with corresponding 'finished' records). But, I guess with this query I would never know that as the limit is applied on the inner query.

Comment: @sugantha Updated the answer. To delete both rows with `started` and 'finished' statuses you just don't need `AND status = 'Started'` condition in `JOIN`. Now in order to know how many rows were deleted you can use `ROW_COUNT()` right after delete. Just know that since you group and delete pairs it'll be 2x rows (meaning `LIMIT 1000` will delete first 2000 such rows). Now you just execute this query with appropriate LIMIT several times until you have `0` return from `ROW_COUNT()`. The query itself is safe to run as many times as you want. If there are no pairs nothing will be deleted.

Comment: @sugantha Did it help? Do you need more help with your question?

Comment: @Peterm.. sorry I am getting to this late..Thanks for your suggestion. Yes, I do understand and it works as you said, but I realize I have oversimplified my question. One criteria that I missed is, a 'Finished' record can have multiple 'Started' records. so, instead of count(*)=2, is there a way to achieve this. A condition like, this 'group' should have at least one 'Finished' record for being returned to the outer query..?

Comment: @sugantha You're quite welcome :) See updated answer for a solution to your follow up question. You need many `started` and exactly one `finished` then you change it to `HAVING SUM(status = 'Started')  > 0 AND SUM(status = 'Finished') = 1`

Comment: @Peterm.. Will this do the same..? " HAVING min(status)='Finished' ". This would return the group only if the minimum varchar is 'Finished' I hope.. since, the criteria includes a single 'Finished' record with no 'Started' records too..

Comment: @sugantha No it wouldn't work correctly. If you want to match 0 or more rows with `status='Started'` and one with `status='Finished'` then do either `HAVING MAX(status = 'Started') >= 0 AND MAX(status = 'Finished') = 1` or `HAVING SUM(status = 'Started') >= 0 AND SUM(status = 'Finished') = 1`

Answer (score 1):

Try these queries:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE FSESSION_TEMP
(
    Temp_Session_Id varchar(255)
);

INSERT INTO FSESSION_TEMP 
(
SELECT a.Session_Id FROM
    FSESSION a, 
    FSESSION b
WHERE 
    a.Status = 'Started' and 
    b.Status = 'Finished' and
    a.Session_ID = b.Session_ID
  LIMIT 2
);


DELETE FROM 
    FSESSION 
WHERE 
    Session_ID in (SELECT * FROM FSESSION_TEMP)
;

DROP TABLE FSESSION_TEMP;
```

Here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7844a/3). I've set LIMIT at 2 to show that it works. You still need to change it to 1000.

It seems that you need to use a temporary table for this for 2 reasons:

1) MySQL doesn't let you delete from a table when you use the same table in a subquery

2) For the multiple-table syntax, DELETE deletes from each tbl_name the rows that satisfy the conditions. In this case, ORDER BY and LIMIT cannot be used (Taken straight out of the [MYSQL DELETE manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html))

---

There is one way to circumvent the restrictions by using the `DELETE` syntax with `JOIN` and joining the original table (where rows will be deleted from) with a derived table (identical to the above temporary one):

```
DELETE fdel
FROM 
    FSESSION fdel
  JOIN
    (
    SELECT a.Session_Id 
    FROM
        FSESSION a
      JOIN 
        FSESSION b
      ON a.Session_ID = b.Session_ID
    WHERE 
        a.Status = 'Started' and 
        b.Status = 'Finished' 
      LIMIT 2
    ) ftemp
  ON ftemp.Session_ID = fdel.Session_ID
;
```

Comment: I'll give +1 because it's a valid sloution - although it is possible to write the DELETE with LIMIT in one statement.

Comment: Added a way and deleted my previous comments.

Comment: The 2nd query works for me, for deleting 'Started' records exclusively, which was indeed my original question. So, thank you for this.