# Deleting rows in a single database table based on the values of other rows

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have a fairly complex requirement I would like to solve using SQL in a Postgres DB. I'm sure this would be addressed in any order management system however I cannot find anything of a similar nature.

I have the following table (and values):

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE1 (
    ID varchar(8), 
    ORIG_ID varchar(8), 
    STATUS varchar(8), 
    VALIDITY varchar(8)
);

INSERT INTO TABLE1
    (ID, ORIG_ID, STATUS, VALIDITY)
VALUES
    ('1', '1', 'REPLACED','DAY'), 
    ('2', '1', 'REPLACED','DAY'),
    ('3', '1', 'FILLED','DAY'),
    ('4', '4', 'REJECTED','DAY'),
    ('5', '5', 'PARTIAL','GTC'),
    ('6', '6', 'EXPIRED','GTD'),
    ('7', '7', 'REPLACED','GTD'),
    ('8', '7', 'PARTIAL','GTD'),
    ('9', '9', 'FILLED', 'GTD'),
    ('10', '10', 'NEW', 'DAY'),
    ('11', '11', 'NEW', 'GTD'),
    ('12', '12', 'DFD', 'GTD'),
    ('13', '13', 'REPLACED', 'GTD'),
    ('14', '13', 'FILLED', 'GTD')
;
```

N.B -

- Please ignore the data types on the fields
- The final table may have thousands of entries to process
- The above can be pasted directly into SQL Fiddle if required (PostgreSQL 9.3.1)

The requirements I have are:

Delete all entries that have a STATUS of either:

```
FILLED, EXPIRED, REJECTED, CANCELLED
PARTIAL/NEW - If the VALIDITY is not GTD/GTC (i.e. only DAY)
REPLACED - Unless there are other entries with the same ORIG_ID in a PARTIAL/NEW STATUS and not GTD/GTC (still working orders)

TBD - To Be Deleted:
TBD ('1', '1', 'REPLACED','DAY'), 
TBD ('2', '1', 'REPLACED','DAY'),
TBD ('3', '1', 'FILLED','DAY'),
TBD ('4', '4', 'REJECTED','DAY'),
    ('5', '5', 'PARTIAL','GTC'),
TBD ('6', '6', 'EXPIRED','GTD'),
    ('7', '7', 'REPLACED','GTD'),
    ('8', '7', 'PARTIAL','GTD'),
TBD ('9', '9', 'FILLED', 'GTD'),
TBD ('10', '10', 'NEW', 'DAY'),
    ('11', '11', 'NEW', 'GTD'),
    ('12', '12', 'DFD', 'GTD'),
TBD ('13', '13', 'REPLACED', 'GTD'),
TBD ('14', '13', 'FILLED', 'GTD')
```

I've tried looking and the closet I could find was the following:

[Delete with join on the same table and limit clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18651992/delete-with-join-on-the-same-table-and-limit-clause)

However I couldn't get it to work while incorporating the requirements above.

As this will be run at the end of day I have had a few thoughts in such as changing all entries with VALIDITY of DAY, setting STATUS to EXPIRED. Then just deleting them all but then still hit the issue of STATUS with the GTD/GTC orders. I'm unsure if this would also be faster than handling it all under the same logic.

Any help (or new ideas) would be appreciated on how to tackle this issue.

Comment: By your logic, row with ID 7 should be deleted, or am I wrong?  ID 8 has the same ORIG_ID, but it is in GTD status.

Comment: I want ID 7 to remain as ID 8 is still "active" in that it is a GTD and in a Parital state. I want to keep the audit of the working order. ID 7 is the previous state of ID 8 and I want to keep it in the DB. After reading it a few more times I can see that I wasn't as clear as I thought I was being when I wrote this apologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Delete from table1
WHERE status in ('FILLED','EXPIRED','REJECTED','CANCELLED')
OR (status in ('PARTIAL','NEW') AND validity not in ('GTD','GTC'))
OR (status = 'REPLACED' and orig_ID not in 
    (select ORig_ID from table1 where status in ('PARTIAL','NEW')));
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9e465/28/0

Comment: Thanks for your answer, marked as answer as executed in 2ms over 51ms for hi4ppl's on SQL Fiddle

Comment: This sentence not include `AND VALIDITY IN ('GTD','GTC')` when `REPLACED` case.

Answer (score 0):

what is your PostgreSQL  version ?

anyways here is what I come up with

```
delete from TABLE1 where
STATUS in ('FILLED','EXPIRED','REJECTED','CANCELLED') or
STATUS in (select STATUS from TABLE1 where STATUS in ('PARTIAL','NEW')
           and VALIDITY!='DAY') OR
STATUS in (select status from TABLE1 where STATUS ='REPLACED'
           and orig_ID not in 
           (select ORig_ID from table1 where status in ('PARTIAL','NEW')))
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9e465/54

Comment: just for the record mine also shows 1MS not 45MS here is screenshot maybe your net slow...[link]http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=e18dq8&s=8#.VKLAAsAKA

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm mistaken, there's either an error in the output in the OP, or the logic.

```
DELETE 
FROM TABLE1 AS T
WHERE STATUS IN ('FILLED', 'EXPIRED', 'REJECTED', 'CANCELLED')
  OR ( STATUS IN ('PARTIAL', 'NEW')
      AND VALIDITY NOT IN ('GTD', 'GTC') )
  OR ( STATUS = 'REPLACED'
  AND NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT 1
     FROM TABLE1 tbl1
     WHERE T.ID <> tbl1.ID
       AND T.ORIG_ID = tbl1.ORIG_ID
       AND tbl1.STATUS IN ('PARTIAL', 'NEW')
       AND tbl1.VALIDITY NOT IN ('GTD', 'GTC')
    ) 
  );
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9e465/16

EDIT:  It seems OP means

"REPLACED - Unless [it does not have GTD/GTC status ] and there are other entries with the same ORIG_ID"

rather than

"REPLACED - Unless there are other entries with the same ORIG_ID [that do not have a GTD/GTC status]"

Comment: You are including the ID '7' for delete. That's wrong.

Comment: OP's logic states that it should be deleted.  There are no other entries with ORIG_ID 7 in PARTIAL/NEW status that do NOT have a validity of GTD/GTC.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this DELETE sentence:

```
DELETE FROM TABLE1 as MASTER 
WHERE 
  STATUS IN ('FILLED', 'EXPIRED', 'REJECTED', 'CANCELLED') OR
  (STATUS IN ('PARTIAL','NEW') AND VALIDITY NOT IN ('GTD','GTC')) OR
  (STATUS='REPLACED' AND ID NOT IN
    (SELECT ORIG_ID FROM TABLE1 OTHER 
      WHERE OTHER.ORIG_ID=MASTER.ID AND 
      STATUS IN ('PARTIAL','NEW') AND VALIDITY IN ('GTD','GTC')));
```

[SQL Fiddle Example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9e465/65) (With SELECT sentence)

Comment: Why are you comparing ID to ORIG_ID?  OP didn't state that.  As I mentioned before, either his logic is wrong, or his output is wrong.

Comment: I understood that we can't delete still working orders... I supposed